# Does god forgive those who are not aware of hindu traditions?

Tags: gods, tradition

In recent days, when you ask someone that what is hinduism, there are many chances that you will get incorrect answers. This might be because the current education system that does not teach about religion or competitiveness among people to grow higher levels in career.

Was there any time earlier this kind of situation in history. I heard that before Adi Shankaracharya, people have so much of dilemma about what is hinduism exactly, but he raised to clear all their questions and taught them many things about religion. One more scenario is that the Lord Krishna told to Arjuna that he given the gita information to Lord Surya at first but as time lapsed, everyone forgot, until he gave that information to Arjuna.

What will happen to those who does not follow hindu principles because of poor knowledge of hindu rituals. Does god forgive them as they are not aware of these hindu principles. I think governments must take steps to educate their people about their religion to create good people in society like our kings did in the past.

Comment: I do not think there is anything to forgive or to punish as far as a person is concerned. I was born in a non-vegetarian family, and stayed non-vegetarian for some years more, even after I had the conscience to know it is immoral. Maybe I will receive the result of this as something very horrible, or maybe as something mild. The thing is, I cannot control what will happen to me, so why waste a lot of time contemplating what will be the results of our karma. Just accept what happens, maybe you will feel sad, but just accept it.

Comment: We must remember what is written in Rama Raksha Stotram, "Matha Ramo, math pitha Ramachandra,
Swami Ramo, math sakha Ramachandra,
Sarvaswam may Ramachandro dayalu,
Na anyam naiva jane na jane., 30" Hence, our eternal friend will not treat us wrongly, he will treat those unaware of even his name justly as he is greatest of all. So we do not need to worry of such things. But, I agree that government should spread Hinduism.

Comment: He does. However, with Google around in your mobile phone you can't claim that an excuse any more can you ? The intention matters....

Comment: God always forgives everybody, whether you believe in him or not, that is the greatness of god

Comment: @UpInAir, God does not forgive everybody. He only forgives those who ask for forgiveness/repent. Otherwise everyone can break the rules all the time without fear of punishment

Comment: @UpInAir everyone has to face the results of his karma. There is no exception.

Comment: your question shows a lot of christian influence. asking for forgiveness for something you're not aware of is a ingrain christian belief, not hindu. If a person is good, thinks about God and commits good acts, you reap good karma. if you commit bad acts and think bad thoughts, you reap bad karma.